# Как ждать ответ от пользователя Aiogram 3 Telegram Bot

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram-3.x

У меня есть Телеграм бот на Python на библиотеке Aiogram, которому мне надо написать команду, после которой он будет ждать следующее сообщение от меня. То есть к примеру я пишу боту "Привет", он пишет мне "Введите имя" и после чего бот должен ждать сообщение от меня. Соответственно, я не могу через if проверять сообщение, ведь я не знаю, что напишет пользователь. Так, человек должен попасть в некий цикл, внутри которого не будут реагировать другие команды, он выйдет из него только когда напишет имя. Я пытался создать другой обработчик сообщений внутри основного, но не вышло.

Comment: https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/dev-3.x/examples/finite_state_machine.py

Comment: Большое спасибо!